# VBA - how to skip over empty cells in a loop?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to build a code that allows me to generate a list of dates from multiple date ranges, and match the dates to an adjacent cell.

As i'm trying to automate this process, the issue i have is the raw data has empty rows between the date ranges. So question is, how do i get the code to skip the empty rows in the loop?

This is what i have so far:

```
Sub Dates()

Dim dStart As Date
Dim dEnd As Date
Dim dDate As Date
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim iColDate As Integer

iCol = 6
iColDate = 6

Do While Cells(iCol, 3).Value <> ""
    dStart = Format(Cells(iCol, 3).Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    dEnd = Format(Cells(iCol, 4).Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    For dDate = dStart To dEnd
        Cells(iColDate, 7).Value = dDate
        Cells(iColDate, 6).Value = Cells(iCol, 2).Value
        iColDate = iColDate + 1
    Next
    iCol = iCol + 1
Loop


End Sub
```

Would appreciate any help at all. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I think if you add `Or Worksheetfunction.Counta(Rows(iCol)) = 0` on your `Do While`  loop that will check if the cell is blank, or if the row is empty.  (Why do you have `iCol` as a row variable? Just curious)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Rows.Count` with a `FOR loop` instead, this way you check for the last row before running the loop and avoid getting kicked out of the loop if a cell in row C is empty:

```
Sub Dates()

Dim dStart As Date
Dim dEnd As Date
Dim dDate As Date
Dim iColDate As Integer
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim loop1 As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

iColDate = 6

For loop1 = 6 To lastrow
    dStart = Format(Cells(iCol, 3).Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    dEnd = Format(Cells(iCol, 4).Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    For dDate = dStart To dEnd
        Cells(iColDate, 7).Value = dDate
        Cells(iColDate, 6).Value = Cells(iCol, 2).Value
        iColDate = iColDate + 1
    Next
Next loop1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping to the first empty row, calculate where the last row is first.

```
  Dim lLastRow As Long
  lLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Then use an Indexed `For..Next` loop instead of a `Do..While` loop

```
Dim lIndex as long
For lIndex = 1 to lLastRow

' do stuff here

Next
```